# How to create n lists of random sizes with random numbers?

Tags: c++

The problem is the following:

I want to create a k amount of lists, where k is inputted by the user. The size of each list will be a random number from 100 to 200. Then, each list will be filled with random numbers ranging from 0 to 50.

So for example if the user inputs 2 as the number k of lists that will be created, I will have to create 2 lists with a random size no less than 100 and no more than 200. Let's say the first random size is 120 and the second 150. Then, I have to fill the first list with 120 random numbers from 0 to 50 and the second one with 150 random numbers from 0 to 50. This is what I've thought of but there must be several errors that I don't understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void output() {

};

int main() {

    int k;
    cout << "What is the number k of lists?" << endl;
    cin >> k;

    //I googled this part to generate random numbers
    random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    mt19937 gen(rd()); // seed the generator
    uniform_int_distribution<int> list_size_distribution(100, 200);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> data_element_distribution(0, 50);

    auto random_list_size = bind(list_size_distribution, gen);
    auto random_element = bind(data_element_distribution, gen);

    int lists[k][200];
    
    //I thought of maybe creating k amount of lists with a size of 200 and fill everything with -1 at the 
    //start?
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<200; j++) {
            lists[k][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    //Something is terribly wrong here for sure
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<random_list_size(); j++) {
            lists[i][j] = random_element();

            //Print everything to see if it's correct
            cout << lists[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << "END OF LIST" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int lists[k][200];` is invalid C++, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: `j<random_list_size()`: you regenerate random value each time, you have to store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) to generate values, and store them in a `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    int k;
    std::cout << "What is the number k of lists?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> k;

    //I googled this part to generate random numbers
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> list_size_distribution(100, 200);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> data_element_distribution(0, 50);

    auto random_list_size = std::bind(list_size_distribution, gen);
    auto random_element = std::bind(data_element_distribution, gen);

    auto generate_vector = [&](){
        std::vector<int> vec(random_list_size()); // create a vector with random number of elements
        std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), random_element); // assign each element
        return vec;
    }
    
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> lists(k); // create k vector<int>s
    std::generate(lists.begin(), lists.end(), generate_vector); // assign each element

    for (auto & list : lists) {
        for (auto val : list) {
            std::cout << val << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << "END OF LIST" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it made me understand a lot of things.!

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> k;
// ...
int lists[k][200];
```

The size of an array variable must be a compile time constant in C++. `k` is not compile time constant, therefore the program is ill-formed. The array must be allocated dynamically in order to use a dynamic size. You can use `std::vector` for example.